# Hartshorne Exercise III.9.5(d)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here is the definition for very flat families:
[image]

[image]

When trying to prove (d):
$X_{(t)}$ is an algebraic families of normal varieties parameterized by a non-singular curve,so it's flat.Its Hilbert polynomial is actually independent of $t$.
For sufficiently large $d$,$\text{dim}_{k(t)}(S_t/I_t)_d$ is independent of $t$.

My questions:

> 1.When $X$ is projectively normal,is it true that $H^0(X,O_X(d))=(S/I)_d,\forall d\geq 0$?
>
> 2.When $X$ is projectively normal,is it true that the Hilbert regularity $r= 0$(namely the least integer $r$ for which $\text{dim}_k H^0(X,O_X(r))=\text{HP}_X(r)$,where HP$_X$ is the Hilbert polynomial for $O_X$)?

If 1. and 2.hold,the conclusion just follows.I wonder if they are true or not,and could you please give me hints on (d)?thanks for your help.

Comment: okay,seems 1. is true.